# How do I prevent reload visible button and hiding button using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have some of problem , if i click `Button1`, and then hide `Button1` and Visible `Button2` and `Button3`. It looks working good, but when i click `Button1`, Page reloaded and then scroll up using mobile page.

aspx code.

```
<asp:Button id="Button1" runat="server"  class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"  OnClick="Button1_Click" 
Text="11:00AM" style= "font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;" />
<asp:button id="Button2" runat="server" class="btn btn-outline-info"  OnClick="Button2_Click" 
Text="Confirm"/>
<asp:button id="Button3" runat="server" class="btn btn-outline-info"  OnClick="Button3_Click" 
Text="11:00AM"/>
```

CS Code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button1.Visible = true;
    Button2.Visible = false;
    Button3.Visible = false;
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Button2.Visible = true;
    Button3.Visible = true;
    Button1.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: Does my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62709561/5519709) solve your problem?

Comment: no.. it is not working.. still load page.. also , if i click difference button , my previous button need to be back of   Button1.Visible = true; Button2.Visible = false; Button3.Visible = false;